# Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration in an angular 11 workspace importing mock component from library to project

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am getting a `Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration`

My setup is quite standard (I haven't updated much of the conifg)

There is one angular project and one angular library in a workspace

```
 -common
 --src
 ---lib
 ----components 
 -----input
 -website
 --src
 ---app
 ----sign-up
```

I have a mock folder inside the input component that defines the @input and @output to use in tests. The app builds fine with the common component imported in, but tests are erroring.

Mock component

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { InputConfig } from '../input.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-input',
  templateUrl: '',
})
export class MockInputComponent {
  @Input() config: InputConfig;
  @Output() valueChange: EventEmitter<string | number> = new EventEmitter<string | number>();
}
```

Test set up

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { MockInputComponent } from '@common/components/partials/input/mocks/mock-input.component';

import { SignUpComponent } from './sign-up.component';

describe('SignUpComponent', () => {
  let component: SignUpComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SignUpComponent>;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync( () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SignUpComponent, MockInputComponent],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SignUpComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

My tsconfig

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@common/*": ["projects/common/src/lib/*"],
      "@website/*": ["projects/website/src/*"]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2019", "dom"],
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

In my library I have a common input, it all works fine in the project component, but when trying to import the mock of the component it gives that error when running tests. I assume there is some set up/config I haven't done yet, but I am scratching my head.

Full error

```
Error: Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks' in '/Users/julian/other/idea-2/web'
resolve '/Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks' in '/Users/julian/other/idea-2/web'
  using description file: /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    root path /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/website
      using description file: /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/package.json (relative path: ./projects/website/Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks)
        no extension
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/website/Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks doesn't exist
        .ts
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/website/Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks.ts doesn't exist
        .tsx
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/website/Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks.tsx doesn't exist
        .mjs
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/website/Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks.mjs doesn't exist
        .js
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/website/Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks.js doesn't exist
        as directory
          /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/website/Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks doesn't exist
    using description file: /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/package.json (relative path: ./projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks is not a file
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks.ts doesn't exist
      .tsx
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks.tsx doesn't exist
      .mjs
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks.mjs doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks.js doesn't exist
      as directory
        existing directory
          using path: /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/index
            using description file: /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/package.json (relative path: ./projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/index)
              no extension
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/index doesn't exist
              .ts
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/index.ts doesn't exist
              .tsx
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/index.tsx doesn't exist
              .mjs
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/index.mjs doesn't exist
              .js
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/index.js doesn't exist

Error: ./projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/mock-input.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './' in '/Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks'9m
resolve './' in '/Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks'
  Parsed request is a directory
  using description file: /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/package.json (relative path: ./projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/package.json (relative path: ./projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks)
      as directory
        existing directory
          using path: /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/index
            using description file: /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/package.json (relative path: ./projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/index)
              no extension
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/index doesn't exist
              .ts
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/index.ts doesn't exist
              .tsx
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/index.tsx doesn't exist
              .mjs
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/index.mjs doesn't exist
              .js
                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                /Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/index.js doesn't exist
[/Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/index]
[/Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/index.ts]
[/Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/index.tsx]
[/Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/index.mjs]
[/Users/julian/other/idea-2/web/projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/index.js]
 @ ./projects/common/src/lib/components/partials/input/mocks/mock-input.component.ts 2:0-50 16:18-38
 @ ./projects/website/src/app/sign-up/sign-up.component.spec.ts
 @ ./projects/website/src sync \.spec\.ts$
 @ ./projects/website/src/test.ts
```

Comment: Did you solve this? It looks like you need to prefix your paths with `./`

Comment: Oh my I haven't, I really hope it was this simple! Will let you know when I get a change to work on this again. Thank you.